# Android SharedPreference do not working

Tags: android

I am writing a code to the app execute a function only once. The problem that the getSharedPreference always return false (see first line) even if I close and open the application.

```
boolean firstboot = context.getSharedPreferences("BOOT_PREF",context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("firstboot", true);

    if(firstboot)
    { 

        context.getSharedPreferences("BOOT_PREF",context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("firstboot", false).commit();

        Log.d(TAG, "first" );
    }
    else
        Log.d(TAG, "not first time" );
```

What I am doing wrong?

Best regards

Comment: If you uninstall the app entirely and use the app for the first time, this will show "true", every appstart after that will show "false". That is how your code is written.

Comment: If it's still doesn't work, can you say from where you call this method? onActivityCreate or something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you open and close the application the preferences won't change, that's the whole point of shared preferences, think of it as a simple database that stores unique information.

If you want to reset the shared preferences you can either: uninstall and reinstall the application, force close the application and clear all data or add the code to clear it:

```
context.getSharedPreferences("BOOT_PREF", context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().commit();
```